# Vertically aligning text inside a bootstrap column

Tags: html, css

I have minimal CSS and HTML knowledge and would like to achieve the following: I am using a WordPress theme that uses Bootstrap, and I want to create a row with two columns. Left column has an image, right column has a headline that should be vertically centered. I am using a column shortcode

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            IMAGE
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            HEADLINE
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me how to center my headline vertically?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: what version of bootstrap and show your code

Comment: If you have a minimal css then you share it here so that we can find the bug or atleast have a look at it

Comment: add `display: flex;` and `align-items:center` to the div in which you want the items to be placed in the vertical center position

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using `Bootstrap 4`. You can use the below snippet**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
   <img src="" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
   Your heading
  </div>
</div>
```

**If you are using `Bootstrap 3.x.x`. You can use the below snippet**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <img src="" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 flex-vcenter">
   Your heading
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (**only if Bootstrap ver is 3**)

```
.flex-vcenter {
   display: flex
   align-items: center
 }
```

Comment: This did not not work, however if I apply  the class flex-vcenter to the row, then it works.

Comment: What version are you using? Can you create a fiddle? There might be height issue.. `height: 100%`  for column... If still does not work please share fiddle